# Why is the exponent in a denormalized float E = 1 - bias?

Tags: floating-point, bit, denormalized

For example, with 32 bit denormalized floats, the exponent would be -126. What is the significance of -126 in this context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in WIkipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top bit of the mantissa (sgnificand) can not be binary `1.` anymore, so the top bit is at most binary `0.1`.

With an exponent of `-126`, the highest denormal is `0.1111... x 2^-126`. The next higher value is the smallest normal, with value `1.000... x 2^-126`.

They chose that value so the ranges of denormals and normals neither overlap, nor leave an ugly gap between them.